# Center Multiple Divs Vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center divs using these code but it's just centering vertical.
I want them horizontal.

HTML

```
<div class='test'>
<div class='test1'>
<img class='gamespic' src='img/{$row['pictures']}'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.test{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.test1 {  
width: 220px;  
height: 300px;  
    border: solid 2px #000;  
    content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: It does center horizontally, http://jsfiddle.net/oruj7066/

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS like this, I have also added full page coverage just in case (but you can remove it)

```
.test {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align: center;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#fc0;
    position:absolute;
}
.test1 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;
    margin-left:-110px;
}
```

[See bootply here](http://jsfiddle.net/vspwz6a9/)

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a wordpress page. I cant use "position:absolute;". The whole page gets messed up. Here is my whole divs.`<div class='container-full-width' id='page_section_section'>
 <div class='container'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
   <div id='container' class='row-fluid'>
    <div id='content' class=' span12'>
     <article style='border-radius:3px;'>

<div class='test'>
<div class='test1'>
<img class='gamespic' src='img/{$row['pictures']}'></div>
</div>






     </article>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>`

Comment: I think you missed the **"I have also added full page coverage just in case (but you can remove it)"** part. You really don't need ANYTHING in .test, as a matter of fact you can add `position:relative`, then simply add the code for `.test1`

Comment: If I add more then 1 div like that `<div class='test1'> <img src='img/{$row['pictures']}'></div>
<div class='test1'> <img src='img/{$row['pictures']}'></div>`, it's centering well. But there is only one div. When I add image, it also create a new div but these are centering vertically

Comment: I tested some different ways. If I add a line (html or just a name it doesn't matter) from db, it looks vertical but if I add the code directly `<div>bla bla</div><div> bla bla</div>` it looks horizontal. I have no idea what is the problem :(